# Custom implicit conversion with lists of UUID Anorm 2.3

Tags: postgresql, scala, anorm

i need to define anorm implicit conversion for lists of UUIDs in this code sample:

```
 case class users(
    name = String
 )

 val userParser: RowParser[users]= {
    get[String]("name") map {
        case name => users(name)
    }
 }

def getUsersNames():List[users] = {
   val uuids = List("a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11", "a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11", "a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11") 

   DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
   return SQL("SELECT name FROM user WHERE uuid IN({uuids})").on( 'uuids -> uuids ).as(users.*)
  }
}
```

i get UUIDS  as string from a form. 
I know that i need to do a implicit conversion but i cant find how to do it (googled many things but i can't get it ...)

i already have implicit type conversion for UUID to statement that work well:

```
  implicit val uuidToStatement = new ToStatement[UUID] {
    def set(s: java.sql.PreparedStatement, index: Int, aValue: UUID): Unit = s.setObject(index, aValue)
  }
```

all i need is implicit conversion for List[String] or List[UUID] to statment...

*also if you have a link with well explained examples about toStatement[] and custom anorm implicit conversion i'll be very grateful*

thanks in advance!

Comment: There is example about custom `ToStatement` in the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAnorm#Custom-parameter-conversions). What is the issue with the current query?

Comment: i get this error :  `play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[PSQLException: ERREUR: operator does not exist : uuid = character varying`     and for your link,  i'm new to scalla and i can't find how to replace "??? // Sets |value| on |statement|"

Comment: I doubt that related to Anorm, but to the underlying PostgreSQL statement; `SQL"SELECT name FROM user WHERE uuid::VARCHAR IN ($uuids)"`

Comment: this show me an error :` PSQLException: ERREUR: syntax error near « $ »` i think it's because i use play 2.3

Comment: `SQL(".. WHERE uuid::VARCHAR IN ({uuids})").on("uuids" -> ..)` (updating Anorm would be a good idea anyway)

Comment: i've already tryed that and i get same error as mentionned in my post . but i'm pretty sure that i need to set implicit conversion with anorm setObject.

Comment: Take care to the `::VARCHAR`; The type mismatch is on the PostgreSQL side